# Работа с web.xml (Spring MVC + MySQL)

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Можете проверить правильно ли я написал код в web.xml. Хочу вывести ошибку 404 страница не найдена.

Web XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>



<error-page>
    <location>/views</location>
</error-page>
```

Error Controller

```
package fallen.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "errors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

        ModelAndView errorPage = new ModelAndView("errorPage");
        String errorMsg = "";
        int httpErrorCode = getErrorCode(httpRequest);

        switch (httpErrorCode) {
            case 400: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 400. Bad Request";
                break;
            }
            case 401: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 401. Unauthorized";
                break;
            }
            case 404: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 404. Resource not found";
                break;
            }
            case 500: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 500. Internal Server Error";
                break;
            }
        }
        errorPage.addObject("errorMsg", errorMsg);
        return errorPage;
    }

    private int getErrorCode(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return (Integer) httpRequest
          .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "500Error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void throwRuntimeException() {
    throw new NullPointerException("Throwing a null pointer exception");
}
}
```

ErrorPage JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${errorMsg}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Расположение файлов

Comment: Если работает, значить написано правильно. Если не работает, значить написано не правильно. Вам лучше для начало проверить ваш код, если что-то не работает, то уже от этого создавать вопрос, с указанием что не так, и как должно быть.

Comment: иначе ваш вопрос закроют: 

Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: посмотрите вот тут: возможно вам поможет, https://www.baeldung.com/custom-error-page-spring-mvc

Comment: Если вы делали прямо по нему, у вас ведь строчки разные: `<location>/errors</location>` или это не влияет?

Comment: Я сначала как тот туториал сделал, потом пытался location под свой проект поменять

Comment: при `<location>/errors</location>` все работало?

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "errors", method = RequestMethod.GET)` у вас слушает `/errors`, мне кажется или же тут меняйте, или же `location` следует из править

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то ваш web.xml должен выглядит вот так.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <error-page>
        <location>/views</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Comment: @СтивГейтс рад что помогло. Код был взять из `github` используйте поиск по схожим проектам: https://github.com/gaussic/SpringMVCDemo/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

Comment: @СтивГейтс скорее всего да, происходит редирект, но я не уверен, так как сам этот код не тестировал.

Comment: ок) спасибо))))