# Показать нужную страницу JSP (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Я написал приложение и оно работает, только в одном месте не могу поправить. В моем проекте можно добавлять студента в БД через спринг и после добавления сразу должна появится страница со списком студентов "AllStudent JSP"(но я появляется основная страница index). Как можно реализовать задачу

StudentController

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import  adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;

@Controller
public class StudentController {
    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }

    // Get All Users
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveNewStudent(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/index");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }
        boolean isAdded = studentService.saveStudent(student);
        if (isAdded) {
            mv.addObject("message", "New student successfully added");
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEditedUser(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/index");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(result.toString());
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }
        boolean isSaved = studentService.saveStudent(student);
        if (!isSaved) {

            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        boolean isDeleted = studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        System.out.println("Удаление студента: " + isDeleted);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/index");
        return mv;

    }

}
```

All Student JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css"%></style>
<title>Все студенты</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
    <div class="it">
    <h3>Список всех студентов</h3>
    ${message}
    <br>
    <br>
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>

      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Фото</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>${student.name}</td>
                    <td>${student.surname}</td>
                     <td>Должно быть изображение</td>

                     <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Редактировать</button>
                    <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Удалить</button>



                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>


    </table>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить студента</button></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Add Student JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Home</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="add">
        <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
    <center>
    <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>

        <form:form method="POST" action="addStudent" modelAttribute="student" >
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="Name">Имя</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="Name"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="Surname">Фамилия</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="Surname"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="data" type="file" accept="image/*"
               </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Добавить"></td>



                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
</center>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вы сами код пишите или же кто-то за вас? вы же тут явно делаете редирект на страницу index `redirect:/index` делайте на нужную

Comment: Все я сам сделал) сейчас ответ выложу

Comment: можете помочь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972842/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-web-xml-spring-mvc-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто добавить еще GET

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
        public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
            System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
            mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
            mv.setViewName("allStudents");
            return mv;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView saveNewStudent(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result) {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return new ModelAndView("error");
            }
            boolean isAdded = studentService.saveStudent(student);
            if (isAdded) {
                mv.addObject("message", "New student successfully added");
            } else {
                return new ModelAndView("error");
            }

            return mv;
        }
```